# Destructor inside a destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor

I am trying to delete allocated memories by objects but it is in a form of linked list. Can someone suggest a way?

This is my header file

```
class XKey
{   
public:
    XKey();
    virtual ~XKey();

private:
    char *m_name;
    char *m_value;
    XKey *m_next;
};

class XSection
{   
public:
    XSection();
    virtual ~XSection();  

private:    
    char *m_name;
    XKey *m_keys;
    XSection *m_next;
};

class XIniFile
{
public:
    XIniFile();
    virtual ~XIniFile();

private:
    char *m_name;
    XSection *m_sections;
};
```

This is my program file

```
XKey::~XKey()
{
    delete(m_name);
    delete(m_value);
    m_next = 0;
}

XSection::~XSection()
{
    XKey k;
    XKey ks;

    k = m_keys;
    while (k){
        ks = k;
        k = k->getNext();
        //////////////<<<--- How can I call a destructor here from XKey?
        delete(m_name);
        m_keys = 0;
        m_next = 0;
    }
}

XIniFile::~XIniFile()
{
    XSection *sec;
    XSection *sp;

    sec = m_sections;
    while (sec) {
        sp = sec;
         //////////////<<<--- How can I call a destructor here from XSection?
        delete(m_name);
        m_sections = 0;
    }    

}
```

I have some typos there but please focus on the algorithm how I could call a destructor inside a destructor. Thanks!

Comment: You call the destructor with `delete`, as in `delete k` or `delete s`.

Comment: what do you mean by "calling a destructor"? You don't manually call destructors (unless you are using placement new, but that's another story). They are called automatically when the object is `delete`'d. Also, `delete(sp->getName());` is horrible and is a sign of the lack of encapsulation and single-responsibility in your data structures.

Comment: @BryanChen *Don’t* use pointers. Utterly unnecessary here.

Comment: IMHO all the comments above should form one community answer :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph you mean don't use _raw_ pointers? you can't implement linked list without pointers.

Comment: @BryanChen Not implementing a linked list might be a virtue.  A carryover from C, it seems.

Comment: @Bryan OP’s code isn’t a linked list. I meant not to use pointers here. *Any* pointers, doesn’t matter whether raw or not. And yeah, you very rarely need pointers at all. Smart pointers definitely fill a niche but it’s just that: a niche.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XSection::~XSection()
{
    XKey* k = m_keys;   // must be a pointer!

    while (k){
        XKey* ks = k;   // must be a pointer!
        k = k->getNext();
        if (ks != nullptr) delete ks;
    }
    delete [] m_name; // allocated with new[]?
}
```

this is very c++98, you should consider embracing c++11 (smart pointers)

Comment: In fact, no. The destructor of `XKey` should `delete this->next;` instead. Again, encapsulation and single responsibility. Furthermore: `if (ks != nullptr) delete ks;` - null-checking the object before deletion is useless, `delete nullptr;` is a safe no-op.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: you are right, XKey is a linked-list, thus it should delete itself. I won't edit because std::vector<XKey> (or similar) should have been used

Comment: No you can't say that with such certainity.Classic implementation (without `vector` backend) of such list is OK.Note that the vector does not allow the items to be moved easily.Moving,inserting,erasing..they all would force reallocation/movement of many other entries.This paired with simple `delete[]value;` performed in `XKey::~XKey` would destroy/invalidate many XKeys you happened to keep in local variables.This is exactly an effect you want to prevent when you are using a list rather than array.Only something like vector+sharedpointer makes that possible,but that in turn changes everything.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl that's why we have `std::list` instead for when we need list-like performance characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

If you use RAII with `std::string`, `std::list` and `std::unique_ptr`,
you don't have to manually do something in destructor:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <memory> // unique_ptr

class XKey
{   
public:
    virtual ~XKey() = default;

private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_value;
};

class XSection
{   
public:
    virtual ~XSection() = default;

private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<XKey>> m_keys;
};

class XIniFile
{
public:
    virtual ~XIniFile() = default;

private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<XSection>> m_sections;
};
```

if those classes don't need to be polymorphic, you may use `std::list<T>` instead of `std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>>`.

Comment: i don't really understand lists yet so I'd prefer the answer below. Thanks though..